# In Mac Automator, how can I pull text from an email and paste it into other programs?

Tags: email, automator, pdf

macOS 11.6.5

I receive email orders at my company. The orders are always in the same format. I created some sample data below. Items I need to extract are email address, customer name, shipping address, customer phone number, delivery date, delivery instructions, price, and quantity. These items are in bold.

Gmail - New Order
Order Date: Order Number: Email:
Name: Company: Address: City: State/Province: Postal Code: Phone:
Date Needed:
How Found?:
6/1/2022
**janedoe@yahoo.com**
**Jane Doe**
**123 fake street

VT

12345 5552346690** (note, this is two separate items, a postal code followed by zip code)
Delivery Address
Delivery Details
**6/6/2022**
**Items

deliver at noon, use side door please**
Product
Price
**$8.00**
Quantity
**2**
Total
$16.00

I am new to Automator. I am used to "programming" in Excel. My approach is to create a print plug-in that first takes an order from my email and converts it to a plain text PDF (this is how I generated the sample data above).

Next, I am hoping to assign the items in bold to variables. Then, I would like the program to ask for some user inputs. These inputs would be for product type and shipping method, which I imagine would be stored as variables?

Finally, I was planning to use the record feature in Automator to open up the program I am pasting into, pasting the values from the variables I created into the appropriate spots.

Is this possible in Automator? If so, would someone help me get off the ground with this or point me in a good direction to start? I have been finding bits of code on the forums, but I having a hard time stitching everything together.

[image: Screenshot of program thus far. The"GET Specified Finder Items" is for code testing purposes. Said item will be removed from the final code.]

Below is some code I took from another post, I think this is the start of what I need to read the .txt file. How can I get the "set theFile" to be the file sent to the print plug in?

```
set theFile to "/Users/username/Desktop/test.txt"
set theFileContents to read theFile as text

set AddressStartPosition to offset of "Random Company Ltd" in theFileContents

set AddressEndPosition to offset of "Hampshire" in theFileContents

set FirstPosition to offset of "1.31 Comments" in theFileContents

set SecondPosition to offset of "1.32 Recommendations" in theFileContents

set ThirdPosition to offset of "3.31 Comments" in theFileContents

set ForthPosition to offset of "3.32 Recommendations" in theFileContents

set Address to (characters (AddressStartPosition + 28) thru (AddressEndPosition - 1) of theFileContents) as string
set FirstPageComments to (characters FirstPosition thru (SecondPosition - 1) of theFileContents) as string
set ThirdPageComments to (characters ThirdPosition thru (ForthPosition - 1) of theFileContents) as string



set FullText to Address & FirstPageComments & ThirdPageComments


display dialog FullText
```

Comment: is the line position of these entries fixed, e.g. the name is always in line 8 of the mail text body? or is there some fixed paragraph structure?

Comment: The line position of the entries will be fixed. The example in the post is a close example of what it will look like. I did remove some lines as they contained company specific information, but hopefully that will be easy to adjust.

Comment: @grg code uploaded. I do not know how to set up code to read the file like I would want. I run into other posts talking about shell code, but I cannot figure out how to manipulate that to make it work for my situation

Comment: @slartibartfast, The line position of the entries will be fixed.

Comment: to print a specific text file via e.g. TextEdit see [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7743420).